# Debugging ArgumentError: invalid base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Someone accidentally committed to my master branch (Ruby on Rails serverside) with a new API key in credentials.yml.enc and now when I try to seed my data I'm getting this error:

ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

...

ArgumentError: invalid base64

I reverted everything... or so I thought.

I tried to edit my credentials and I got "Couldn't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?".

What is happening?

Comment: If you are sure you reverted everything, can you open credentials.yml.enc? Does it contains exactly 1 line with encrypted content?

Comment: @nuaky huh it's telling me "Couldn't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?"

Comment: @railroadstonks The `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable was likely changed on the machine you're hitting this error on. Can't say for sure though.

Answer (score 2):

It's happen because you edit `credentials.yml.enc`, you should copy `credentials.yml.enc`

Comment: Thank you, that saved me!  Been trying to figure this out for hours.  Indeed I had copied the **contents** of the file to a new file.  When I copied the file itself, it worked.

Comment: Are there any special characters not carried when you copy and paste the content?